# How to change Axes label color in Kivy garden.graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to change the axes label color in a Kivy graph from garden.graph but I am a beginner and I do not know how.

I have looked at the "__ init __.py" but it is not obvious to me as it is for the background color for example.

Here is the link to GitHub: [kivy-garden/garden.graph](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph)

Also, here is my kv function:

```
Graph:
    id: my_graph1
    # pos: 10, 200
    # size: 470, 300
    size_hint_x: 0.7
    border_color: 0,0,0,1
    x_grid_label: True
    y_grid_label: True
    x_grid: True
    y_grid: True
```

Also, if there are other features that are not obvious - I would appreciate it if you list them below as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Bump! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to change the axis label color in your python (I do not know how to do this in a .kv file).

From [garden.graph's GitHub page](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/__init__.py):

```
graph_theme = {
            'label_options': {
                'color': rgb('444444'),  # color of tick labels and titles
                'bold': True},
            'background_color': rgb('f8f8f2'),  # back ground color of canvas
            'tick_color': rgb('808080'),  # ticks and grid
            'border_color': rgb('808080')}  # border drawn around each graph

graph = Graph(
            xlabel='Cheese',
            ylabel='Apples',
            x_ticks_minor=5,
            x_ticks_major=25,
            y_ticks_major=1,
            y_grid_label=True,
            x_grid_label=True,
            padding=5,
            xlog=False,
            ylog=False,
            x_grid=True,
            y_grid=True,
            xmin=-50,
            xmax=50,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=1,
            **graph_theme)
```

The axis labels can be configured by passing parameters to the kivy.uix.Label object that displays the axis labels.

`label_options` is a dictionary that contains parameters that are passed to the kivy.uix.Label objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to change Graph's features in kv file:

```
Graph:
    id: graph_id
    xmin: 0
    xmax: 10
    ymin: 0
    ymin: 20
    y_grid_label: True
    y_ticks_major: 5
    border_color: (0,0,0,0)
    tick_color: (1,0,0,1)
    label_options: {'color': (1,0,0,1)}
```